# Was the 2023 Ohio train derailment the 'worst environmental disaster in US history'?

Tags: united-states, environment

According to [Impact Nottingham](https://impactnottingham.com/2023/02/east-palestine-ohio-exploring-the-worst-environmental-disaster-in-the-history-of-the-usa/):

> East Palestine, Ohio: Exploring The Worst Environmental Disaster in
> the History of the USA
>
> On 3rd February 2023, a freight train carrying various potentially
> hazardous chemicals derailed in the town of East Palestine in Ohio,
> USA. This tragic environmental disaster is causing the residents of
> East Palestine to fear for their safety, as well as that of the town’s
> water and air. Thomas Martin explores the aftermath of the event, and
> solutions to prevent incidents like in the future.

A similar notion is echoed by [activist Erin Brockovich](https://thehill.com/homenews/state-watch/3871176-erin-brockovich-east-palestine-a-disaster-like-one-ive-never-seen/):

> Environmental activist Erin Brockovich has called the derailment of a
> train carrying hazardous chemicals in East Palestine, Ohio, earlier
> this month a disaster “like one I’ve never seen.”
>
> Brockovich, who discovered that groundwater contamination from Pacific
> Gas and Electric Company was sickening residents in the small town of
> Hinkley, Calif., in the 1990s, told “CNN This Morning” that the East
> Palestine incident feels reminiscent of the disastrous Hinkley case.

Is it true that the [East Palestine train derailment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Ohio_train_derailment) can be considered the "worst environmental disaster in US history"?

Comment: This feels very subjective to me. The choice of metric to use is arbitrary and opinion-based. How could this be answered?

Comment: @Oddthinking is there any (reasonable) metric in which this is true?

Comment: @TimRias: It is the worst in terms of press coverage quality :-0 I think the quoted claims are just too vague though for this site. Almost like claiming X is the worst president ever.

Comment: @Oddthinking One that comes to mind is "How much did it cost to clean up?", but that only works if it's possible to do.

Comment: Voting to close: It is too soon to assess the long-term damages, and even the short-term damages are under a heavy misdirection campaign by the railroad company.

Comment: I think it is too early to tell. The real effects of an environmental disaster usually only become apparent years later.

Comment: @Mindwin Whether it's too soon to tell seems like something that would form part of an answer. Us not knowing the answer doesn't seem like a good reason to close a question, and especially not a good reason to avoid challenging a dubious statement claiming otherwise - the fact that we don't know *is* a refutation. Not to mention that the claim is almost certainly false in this case.

Comment: I disagree with closing this. Subjective isn't the same as unknowable, the size of this event is fixed and unchanging, and "what even is an environmental disaster" borders on sea lioning.

Comment: I voted to close. This is very subjective. I would be OK to reopen if a specific claim is made - it's the most deadly, it's the largest in terms of area, etc.

Comment: @ventsyv the right wing media is playing it up right now, including a visit from Trump to East Palestine. It's a major piece of news and tons of people are making this claim. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @JonathanReez I changed my mind, I voted to re-open. There seem to be plenty of questions that are similarly opinion based that have been answered.

Comment: @ventsyv Just because opinion based questions have answered in the past doesn't mean that they should have been.

Comment: @JoeW Sure. But if a reasonable answer can be given, why shouldn't we allow it?

Comment: @JoeW I don't even agree this is opinion based. Some chemicals spilled, we know what the chemicals are, we know what the safety profile of those chemicals is, and we know what historic events have occurred. Saying this is opinion-based eventually goes ad absurdum to "we cant know if a spilled tanker car of milk is worse than a spilled tanker car of vinyl chloride because it's an opinion".

Comment: @CJR it's also now been 3 weeks since the accident and there's a huge national spotlight on the situation so we have *tons* of data.

Comment: @CJR And the issue I have is how do you determine what makes it a worse disaster? Is it the quantity of  chemicals spilled? Is it how harmful they are? Is it how hard it is to clean up? Is it about how long the harm will stay around? You might argue that a smaller spill with less harmful chemicals but it is harder to clean up and stays around longer is worse then one that is larger and more harmful it it is easier and quicker to clean up.

Comment: @ventsyv The point being just because opinion based questions have been answered in the past instead of being closed doesn't mean it was the right thing to do.

Comment: As a side note, article titles are notoriously exaggerated, if not just blatantly false, and there seems to be no mention of it being the "worst" environmental disaster in the article itself. So I'm conflicted about whether that would constitute a "notable claim", since a reasonable person would not take such titles as face value, but the title is still claiming it. And Brockovich just said she hasn't personally seen a disaster as bad, which may very well be the case, even if worse disasters have happened.

Comment: @JoeW the usual metric used is "cost of disaster", which includes both QALYs lost and the cost of cleaning up.

Comment: @JoeW You could take issue with which quantifiable measures are weighted in what ways when talking about "worst" except in this case there are specific counterexamples that are worse in **every** metric. I reiterate that your argument goes ad absurdum to the difference between spilled milk and spilled hazardous chemicals is an opinion.

Comment: @JonathanReez And I am saying that it is not as simple as that.

Comment: @CJR And I disagree with that and contend that it isn't as simple as that and there is going to be some difference in opinion about what makes something worse then something else.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: related https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/how-should-we-deal-with-claims-that-only-appear-in-article-headlines

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Superfund_sites

Answer (score 21):

I'm just going to use Wikipedia for this because the claim is obviously hyperbole.

This is East Palestine:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Ohio_train_derailment

> Of the 51 derailed cars, 11 of them were tank cars which dumped 100,000 gallons of hazardous materials, including vinyl chloride, benzene residue, and butyl acrylate.

Approximately 100 tons of hazardous material was released in a town of 5000 people. So far, no casualties.

This is Love Canal:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Canal

> During the 1940s, the canal was purchased by Hooker Chemical Company, which used the site to dump 19,800 t (19,500 long tons; 21,800 short tons) of chemical byproducts from the manufacturing of dyes, perfumes, and solvents for rubber and synthetic resins.

Approximately 20000 tons of hazardous material was released in a city of 50000 people. Three thousand people lived directly on a hazardous waste landfill including a school with hundreds of children. Extensively documented health effects.

This is Buffalo Creek:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_Creek_flood

> The resulting flood unleashed approximately 132 million US gallons (500,000 cubic metres; 500 million litres) of black waste water, cresting over 30 feet (9.1 m) high, upon the residents of 16 coal towns along Buffalo Creek Hollow. Out of a population of 5,000 people, 125 were killed,[5] 1,121 were injured, and over 4,000 were left homeless

I don't even think East Palestine is the worst currently ongoing environmental disaster in the United States, either in impact or potential scope. I could provide probably hundreds of counterexamples in addition to these two.

Comment: I interpret your commentary as saying the metric of environmental disasters is the weight or volume of the pollutant and the number of people living nearby. Why is that the appropriate measure?

Comment: @Oddthinking the number of people affected *would* be a good measure, at least. This seems to be a proposed (?) set of metrics for measuring severity https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8630994/ though you've definitely got a good point that this is at least somewhat subjective (though I feel like it's at least not *fully* subjective)

Comment: Picking a nit: 100,000 gallons is about 400 metric tons (intentionally switching units), not 100. It's still a tiny amount compared to Love Canal or Buffalo Creek.

Comment: hazardous materials cannot be compared like that. I would bet the chemical by-products were orders of magnitude less dangerous than the vinyl chloride and others released in Ohio. The future will tell how many cancers will occur.

Comment: This is fine if you compare sheer volume. But you should also compare toxicity. Another aspect you might consider is the effect on the environment (wild life, ground & water contamination, etc) not just casualties.

Comment: @ventsyv I don't think it's worth talking about the environmental contamination unless there are other chemicals not on the wikipedia list, as they're all pretty rapidly biodegraded. There's nothing here like dioxins or heavy metals that would never go away.

Comment: @CJR So say so in your answer. If it's easy to clean up and doesn't have long term effects, is it really a disaster?

Comment: @fyrepenguin: that criteria is for "natural disasters", not environmental ones, so YMMV if that's the best metric. How would you compare an oil spill in which some people died but released 1/10 of the amount that another did, in which nobody died, etc.

Comment: @Fizz if you can come up with any metric by which this train derailment is more serious than Love Canal discussing relevant importance of metrics is useful. I can't think of a single one, besides perhaps something based on number of tweets.

Comment: @CJR: did any presidential candidates visit the Love Canal in the aftermath? (I'm not saying it's a good criterion, but if you want to explain interest...)

Comment: @CJR: more seriously, do you know any estimates how many animals have died due to the Love Canal? I did find one for East Palestine, supposedly 43,000 https://eu.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2023/02/24/east-palestine-train-derailment-fish-animal-deaths/11337404002/

Comment: OTOH Deepwater Horizon exceeded that... https://www.fisheries.noaa.gov/national/marine-life-distress/sea-turtles-dolphins-and-whales-10-years-after-deepwater-horizon-oil#:~:text=An%20estimated%204%2C900%E2%80%937%2C600%20large,on%20sea%20turtle%20nesting%20beaches.

Comment: @Fizz The Love Canal incident was not as immediate as Palestine so comparisons are more difficult. Studies on Love Canal tend to follow issues like epilepsy, miscarriages, and birth defects in people rather than concentrating on the 38k minnows and 6k other animals immediately affected at Palestine. However, there have been studies that the life expectancy of voles has been significantly shortened at Love Canal.

Answer (score 11):

It certainly was a nasty disaster, but the worst environmental disaster in US history? That is extremely dubious. That claim is just newsies and others wanting to get top headlines. Think back to the [Exxon Valdez oil spill](https://darrp.noaa.gov/oil-spills/exxon-valdez), the [Three Mile Island disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Mile_Island_accident), the [Dust Bowl](https://houstonpbs.pbslearningmedia.org/resource/ecological-disaster-ken-burns-dust-bowl/ken-burns-the-dust-bowl/), [Love Canal](https://cumulis.epa.gov/supercpad/SiteProfiles/index.cfm?fuseaction=second.cleanup&id=0201290), the [BP Deepwater Horizon oil spill](https://www.epa.gov/enforcement/deepwater-horizon-bp-gulf-mexico-oil-spill), and the list goes on and on. We won't know the full extent of the damage from the East Palestine train derailment for years. To immediately call it the worst environmental disaster in US history is at best premature, and more likely is plain old headline-grabbing newsiness.

Comment: Was Three Mile Island, say, worse? How did you determine that?

Comment: @Oddthinking: well, the DH spill was at least claimed by some (other) press to be "the biggest" https://www.vice.com/en/article/884z93/the-biggest-environmental-disaster-in-us-history-never-really-ended and even "the worst" https://www.deccanherald.com/content/75657/oil-spill-worst-environmental-disaster.html

Comment: @Oddthinking Exactly. Regarding the East Palestine train derailment, we don't yet know how many lives will be lost or shortened, how many people will be displaced, how much money recovery will cost. To say this was the worst is premature, and I doubt that it is anywhere close to the worst by any reasonable metric.

Comment: @DavidHammen we have tons of data on the effects of different chemicals on the expected lifespan of humans. I think we can make pretty solid predictions about East Palestine, though disappointingly for the right wing media the most likely answer is that the health impact will be close to zero.

Comment: I reject "lives lost" and "lives shortened" as appropriate measures for the severity of **environmental** disasters. Where is the consideration of biodiversity? habitat loss? climate change impacts?

Comment: @JonathanReez Do you have any idea how nasty vinyl chloride is? About 100 metric tons of the stuff were burned in Ohio. Concentrations above 5mg/m^3 in the air count as hazardous for humans. If that stuff gets into contact with water it turns into Hydrochloric acid, one of the strongest acids in existence. This counts as a relatively harmless outcome for vynil chloride.

Comment: @Oddthinking like it or not, people generally don’t care about anything other than themselves. Climate change only gets this much attention because it’s actually a threat to humans.

Comment: @quarague cool. Now do the math and you’ll see that the concentrations in the actual city were nowhere near the truly dangerous thresholds.

Comment: @quarague how does vinyl chloride compare to the stuff dumped in Love Canal for example?

Comment: @user253751 Over the long term, Love Canal was much worse. That said, comparing acute (very short term) disasters such as this train derailment with chronic (much longer term) disasters such as Love Canal is a bit problematic.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently not by number of animals killed either.

The estimate I [found](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2023/02/24/east-palestine-train-derailment-fish-animal-deaths/11337404002/) for East Palestine is 43,000 animals killed, mostly minnows.
In comparison, the Deepwater Horizon spill killed [some](https://www.fisheries.noaa.gov/national/marine-life-distress/sea-turtles-dolphins-and-whales-10-years-after-deepwater-horizon-oil#:%7E:text=An%20estimated%204%2C900%E2%80%937%2C600%20large,on%20sea%20turtle%20nesting%20beaches.) "56,000–166,000 small juvenile sea turtles" and smaller number of other animals.

(And yeah, some other press headlines declared DH the  ["biggest"](https://www.vice.com/en/article/884z93/the-biggest-environmental-disaster-in-us-history-never-really-ended) or ["worst"](https://www.deccanherald.com/content/75657/oil-spill-worst-environmental-disaster.html) environmental disaster in US history, FWTW. DH also features at #2 (behind the Nevada Test Site) in a certain [listicle](https://owlcation.com/stem/-Ten-Worst-Man-Made-Environmental-Disasters-in-American-History), but like with many such pieces, there's no clear criteria given for the ranking.)

OTOH, a CNN piece title "The Gulf spill: America's worst environmental disaster?" [says](http://edition.cnn.com/2010/US/08/05/gulf.worst.disaster/index.html):

> Disasters are hard to rank and tricky to compare, historians say, but they cite several calamities that rival or surpass the [DH] Gulf oil spill in terms of lives lost or affected.
>
> In 1889, for example, a poorly maintained dam collapsed, sending a wall of water crashing through Johnstown, Pennsylvania. The flood killed over 2,200 people and destroyed 1,600 homes.
>
> Historians also cite what happened in blue-collar community of Love Canal, New York, which was built atop more than 20,000 tons of chemical waste and linked to high rates of cancer and birth defects. Hundreds of families were ultimately forced to flee.
>
> In terms of permanently disrupting a way of life for the largest number of Americans, historians say, nothing compares to the 1930s Dust Bowl, a slow-motion disaster sparked by years of shortsighted farming practices and serious drought. Native grasses across the country's heartland were torn up, leaving little to hold the topsoil in place. When the winds kicked up, dust storms turning the sky black could be seen as far away as New York City. About 2.5 million people fled the Dust Bowl in one of the largest migrations in U.S. history. Families abandoned countless farms. That devastated the region's agriculture economy. [...]
>
> In 1910 and 1911, though, more oil spilled onto land in California as a result of the Lakeview Gusher, the consequence of a 1910 well explosion in California's Central Valley. Nearly 380 million gallons are believed to have spilled over nearly a year and a half. That spill, though, directly affected relatively few people and had "a less complicated ecological impact," [Brian Black, an environmental historian at Penn State] said.
>
> Fewer people may have been affected by Love Canal than by the Gulf spill, but petroleum is "not quite as corruptive as the toxins were at Love Canal," Black said; chemicals and radioactive materials can pose a potentially greater long term risk.
>
> The bottom line: it's tough to rank environmental calamities.
>
> "We can't appreciate the magnitude of (some disasters) until their results and implications have had time to play out," Black said.

Comment: Exxon Valdez spill killed an estimated [250,000 sea birds](https://darrp.noaa.gov/oil-spills/exxon-valdez), dwarfing the number killed in the DH spill.

Answer (score 1):

While it is somewhat a matter of opinion what disaster was worst, there are clear examples that were much worse.   I'll just mention one.

The 1944 liquefied natural gas tank [explosion](https://Cleveland%20East%20Ohio%20Gas%20explosion), also in Ohio:

About 131 dead.

79 houses and 2 factories destroyed.

[image]

[Image source](https://www.cleveland.com/metro/2014/10/east_ohio_gas_explosion_70_yea.html)

Comment: This was a disaster but it didn't impact the environment on the long term.

Comment: @Shautieh for long term, the Hanford nuclear site is probably the worst in the US.

Comment: @Shautieh How about the [Centralia mine fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralia_mine_fire) in Pennsylvania?  That happened in 1962, and it's still on fire today, and likely will be for another few centuries.  Zero fatalities, but for long term environmental impact, it's one of the most enduring...

Comment: Also in Ohio, the [Cuyahoga River caught fire at least a dozen times between 1868 and 1969](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/cuyahoga-river-caught-fire-least-dozen-times-no-one-cared-until-1969-180972444/) due to industrial pollution. The last fire in 1969 helped spur the creation of the Environmental Protection Agency. While the pollution has since been curtailed, the environmental impacts of that repeated pollution continue to this day. River sediments remain laden with PCBs, for example.